# Find the best path for a converter from the given list or map

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, java-8, shortest-path

**Question:**
You are given pdf to file converter , file to unicode converter , unicode to image converter  etc ...

```
Eg: A-> b , b -> c , c-> d , d -> e
    Z-> g , g -> e.
```

In the above two ways the shortest , efficient path to convert to e is z->g ,g -> e should be printed..

What is the best possible way to achieve the solution given there are numerous paths that leads to same converter?

EDIT: The paths could be disjoint - 
A -> B is just a representation of how a file can be transformed - Interviewer just want an optimized way of finding the best possible conversion format. 
Let's say Given the following paths in the form of a list or map as key value pairs-

jpg -> pdf , pdf -> text , text ->unicode , unicode -> hex file ,
 jpg -> png , png -> hex file

Find the best possible path to convert jpg to hex file .output should be  jpg -> png , png -> hex file

Comment: Please clarify what is A, B, C,...Z.  are those file formats ? Also are all they connected to each other? or they could be disjoint ?

Comment: Added few points in edit section. Please let me know if it is still unclear

Comment: Just need to model the problem as a graph and then use bfs to find shortest path

Comment: This is a plain vanilla shortest path problem on an undirected graph. Unfortunately, a tutorial about finding shortest paths would be too long for Stack Overflow, but there are plenty of resources out there to teach you how to solve problems like these.

Comment: @FeiXiang I think this is a directed graph, not an undirected graph. That is, the existence of an A => B converter does not imply the existence of a B => A converter.

Comment: @JimMischel Oops, I meant to say "unweighted", not "undirected".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your example:

1. JPG -> PDF; PDF -> TEXT; TEXT->UNICODE; UNICODE->HEX
2. JPG->PNG; PNG->HEX

These represent "Edges" in a graph, so you would build an [adjacency list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list) out of these paths.

If you build a graph it would appear like:

[image]

So the shortest path would be JPG -> PNG -> HEX

But in order to achieve this programatically you would need to do a [Breadth First Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) that guarantees a shortest path from a source to destination node.

You could have multiple [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)) that have no nodes in common.

Do the search on all connected components to get the desired path.

Comment: It´s better to model the edges the other way around, so you can do bfs on the destination format node and when you reach a base node, you are done

Comment: @juvian Do you mean PDF->JPG instead of JPG->PDF? How is that better when I want a path from JPG to HEX ? You may say look for HEX -> JPG, I don't see any improvement in efficiency, am I wrong?

Comment: I think @juvian is talking about reconstructing the shortest path with parent pointers, which gives you the path in reverse.

Comment: @SomeDude the only difference is you know where to start the bfs, in your case you will need to do it from all nodes. Its not a big difference

Comment: @juvian The graph is represented by an adjacency list and to get to a starting node from where bfs needs to be done, one has to traverse the list. If you want to quickly get to the starting node adjacency map may be better but I believe that has some unnecessary overhead compared to adj. list